# Can't get query parameter after changing from Router to HashRouter on React JS

Tags: reactjs, react-router, query-string

This is the content of my app.json

I have the following state :

```
  const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
  const [checkboxes,setCheckkoxes] = React.useState({

    circular: Number(params.has('circular')?params.get('circular'):0),
});
```

Its initial value is based on whether it has the param ('circular') on the URL.

```
<HashRouter basename = {process.env.PUBLIC_URL}> 

<Switch>
      <Route exact path = "/">
      <Root/>
      </Route>
      <Route exact path = {"/Pesquisar/:searchField/:page"} component = {withRouter(Pesquisa)}>
      </Route>
      <Route exact path = {"/documento/:id"} component = {Documento}>
      </Route>
      <Route exact insecure component={ Insecure }/>

  </Switch>
</HashRouter>
```

When I was using Router instead of HashRouter my state was working properly, when I pass the query param 'circular = 1' in the URL, my state was properly signalled to 1. However, after changing it to HashRouter it's not working anymore. Its value is always Zero. What's happening, why am I not able to access window.location.search params after switching from Router to HashRouter?

Answer (score 0):

`URLParams not able to work with react HashRouter` that is a known issue wich is been reported on [github](https://github.com/appbaseio/reactivesearch/issues/824).

In version `v3.0.0-beta.1` they added two new props for complete customisations:

```
- getSearchParams: Function [optional]
```

Enables you to customise the evaluation of query-params-string from the url (or) any other source. If this function is not set, the library will use window.location.search as the search query-params-string for parsing selected-values. This can come handy if the URL is using hash values.

```
- setSearchParams: Function [optional]
```

Enables you to customise setting of the query params string in the url by providing the updated query-params-string as the function parameter. If this function is not set, the library will set the window.history via pushState method.

See [docs](https://github.com/appbaseio/reactive-manual/blob/v3/content/getting-started/ReactiveBase.md#props)